# Image Magick not converting svg file to jpg

Tags: php, cakephp, imagemagick

I am using Image Magick library to convert a .svg file into a jpg but it is creating a blank image. I have checked a lot of forums for it , but was not able to figure out the problem with it. I have a file name abc.svg , which have the following code inside it;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12cm" height="12cm">
<g style="fill-opacity:0.7; stroke:black; stroke-width:0.1cm;">
<circle cx="6cm" cy="2cm" r="100" style="fill:red;"transform="translate(0,50)" /> 
<circle cx="6cm" cy="2cm" r="100" style="fill:blue;"transform="translate(70,150)" />
<circle cx="6cm" cy="2cm" r="100" style="fill:green;"transform="translate(-70,150)"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I am trying to convert it by the following command :

`$convert abc.svg abc.jpg`

But the file I am getting (i.e abc.jpg is simply blank)

Please help me out with the problem, so that I can move ahead with the thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly because JPEG does not support transparency, and is misinterpreting the SVG opacity.  [According to this post on the ImageMagick forums,](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10594) you could try to first flatten the SVG with a background color and then convert it to JPEG.

```
convert image.svg  -background gray  -flatten  output.jpg
convert abc.svg abc.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your SVG file has errors. You are missing a space before the `transform` attribute in your three circles. It converts fine for me with ImageMagick (6.6.9-7 from [Debian](http://www.debian.org)) after I fix that.

But when I try your file in ImageMagick, it doesn't give me an empty file. It gives a few errors and no output file at all. Does your SVG file work in any other program, e.g. [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org)? Does your copy of ImageMagick handle other SVG files?